# Spring Boot Cassandra : c.d.o.d.i.core.session.DefaultSession : [s0] Negotiated protocol version V5 instead of v4

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

Small question regarding Spring Boot and Cassandra please.

I am currently using Spring Boot 2.5.1, with its associated Cassandra connector: spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra also at 2.5.1, which I think in turn utilize the driver 4.11.1

`c.d.o.d.i.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates   : DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.11.1`

Upon application start, I am observing a strange log which I do not understand:

`c.d.o.d.i.core.session.DefaultSession    : [s0] Negotiated protocol version V4 for the initial contact point, but cluster seems to support V5, keeping the negotiated version`

It seems the cluster supports V5 (whatever that is) but my app is "doing negotiation" with V4.

May I ask how I can configure my application, to leverage this cassandra V5 please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The native protocol defines the format of the messages between the driver the Cassandra cluster over TCP connections. Java driver 4 supports protocol versions v3 (C* 2.1), v4 (C* 2.2, 3.x) and v5 (C* 4.0).

Since Cassandra 4.0 is not released yet, native protocol v5 support is still in beta so the Java driver automatically negotiates to protocol v4 (recommended).

You can set `ProtocolVersion` in `CassandraClusterFactoryBean` but it isn't something you need to worry about since the log entry you posted is informational only. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am actually using a Cassandra 4.0, the RC one that is available to download from Apache Cassandra. But I do not use the ```CassandraClusterFactoryBean ```, but using ```CqlSession```. How to use v5 with ```CqlSession``` please? It seems from what you are saying using v5 with a Cassandra 4 might be a good choice

Comment: You'll need to look at Spring Boot docs in order to see how you could instantiate that bean in your code. In any case, it's neither good nor bad to choose v4 over v5 since v5 is still in beta and in the process of being implemented. It has no material difference over your use of C* 4.0 since there are no features for it yet. Again, protocol v4 is recommended. Cheers!